# How to get the revision number of a TeamCity artifact

Tags: teamcity

How do I find the TeamCity revision number of an artifact's last checkin? (NOT the lastest build number)

Answer (score 1):

Teamcity populates a predefined parameter `build.vcs.number.<VCS root ID>` which holds the revision number of the check-in. See [Predefined Build Parameters](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/Predefined+Build+Parameters#) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding the configuration parameter "teamcity.build.id" is used as the artifact revision number.

On Linux environment, the build artifacts can be access from the location - 
"/opt/TeamCity/data/system/artifacts/project.id/buildConfName/teamcity.build.id"

Cheers